# Can't import cross_validation from sklearn in version > 0.20

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

When I import `cross_validation` from `sklearn`:

```
from sklearn import cross_validation
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'cross_validation' from 'sklearn' (/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/__init__.py)
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because ["Can someone please help me" is not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/2564301).

Comment: File "master.py", line 36, in classquandl
    x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test = cross_validate.train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.3)
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'train_test_split'

Comment: Please, *do not* post code in the comments - it is literally unreadable! Edit & update your post instead!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you have to call it as

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate
```

You need to give the following, if you want to do [train test splitting](https://scikit-learn.org/0.18/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split.html)

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
a_train, a_test, b_train, b_test = train_test_split(a, b, 
                                         test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
```

cross validation train test splitting in sklearn is depreciated

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
```

[Deprecated since version 0.18: This module will be removed in 0.20. Use sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split instead](https://scikit-learn.org/0.19/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split.html)

Comment: File "master.py", line 36, in classquandl
    x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test = cross_validate.train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.3)
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'train_test_split'

Comment: Why the title was changed to `"in version > 0.80"`? It should be `"> 0.20"`

Comment: True. Requested for edit! Thanks

Comment: If you have many old names you want to keep in code, set an alias:

    `code`  
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate as cross_validation